# Data Access Library using EF in linux server

Tags: linux, entity-framework, cross-platform, entity-framework-core

I've developed a data access library that exposes some repositories to access a DB using EF6.

I am a bit confused about EF and EF Core, and Asp and Asp Core...

I want to use this library in a WEB API I have to code, to access the data from a mobile phone. (Barcode will be scanned, and used to retrieve data from the db using the repos in the dll)

The Api should be able to work in Linux and Windows servers.

My question is, can I use this library, which uses EF6, to create an API and deploy it in a linux system?

Or should I migrate to EF Core? Or can I use/call it maybe with NodeJS or something like it?

In other words, do I need to use EF Core everytime I want to use the dll/app in a non windows system or can I still use "old" EF? Or maybe I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework runs on .NET Framework. Not .NET Core. .NET Framework only runs on Windows (unless you use Mono, which [has EF support](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/entityframework/)).

.NET Core runs on Windows, Mac OS, and Linux. Therefore, if you intend to run on Linux and use some form of EF and some form of ASP.NET, your best bet is to use EF Core running on .NET Core, and to use ASP.NET Core for the web layer.

Comment: @RafaGomez Keep in mind that just because it has "Core" in the name doesn't mean the framework has to run on .NET Core. It's just that .NET Core is the only version of .NET that runs on Linux (unless you count Mono). EF Core and ASP.NET Core can both run on .NET Framework too. Just something to keep in mind for the future.